# How Can I Erase the Strength of a Grease Pencil Stroke With a Solid--NOT Softened--Brush Effect?

Tags: grease-pencil, geometry, draw-mode

If I use the Strength feature to erase a Grease Pencil stroke, even with a full brush strength of 1.0, I get the softening effect shown in the red square. I want a hard-edged erase effect, one that matches the look of the stroke ends as they appear in the green square.

I'm aware that there is some trickery involved in producing this softening effect, because we aren't working with rasters here, but vectors (or, perhaps more precisely, geometry). Still, if there's trickery at work in producing the softening, it should be possible to create the appearance of a sharp "cut"--even where the underlying geometry wouldn't properly allow a cut--by recourse to the same trickery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Moving a point with zero strenght close to the last point of strenght 1.0 can avoid the fade out effect, but if you want the rounded cap you have to delete the zero strenght vertices.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting that we can change the strength of individual points. It didn't occur to me to make strength changes on a point-level basis. But though that's a creative solution, it's still a tedious workaround that indicates there's no built-in solution to the problem. Also, I'd prefer the rounded tips, but the problem with deleting any stroke points is that I have fills which need to be preserved, and they will get hosed if I start deleting stroke points.

Comment: I generally make a duplicate of the stroke, and use one of them for the stroke and the other for the fill, to avoid conflicts of this kind.

Comment: Okay, but how do you keep those strokes together during deformations or sculpts?

Comment: As they share the same points locations, they get edited and deformed together (give it a try).

Comment: So they do. What isn't clear is how you're achieving the separation, since the material must be different on the stroke-only object than on the fill-only object for them to appear differently. Unlinking the material doesn't allow me to create a completely new one because evidently, material linking happens at the object level, and at that level we only have the grease pencil object, which contains these stroke elements and layers. I'm assuming you aren't using separate grease pencil objects because you wouldn't be able to sculpt them at the same time. So how are you organizing your materials?